# Inline and attachment of pdf in ie in a single page has issue of vanishing content of inline

Tags: jquery, html, pdf, iframe

**Please help me out on this**

I used iframe for showing and downloading pdf in a single page without refresh. Here is my html

```
<html>
<body>
    <iframe src="Inline" width="300" height="500"></iframe> 
    <iframe src="Inline" width="300" height="500"></iframe> 
    <iframe src="Inline" width="300" height="500"></iframe> 
    <iframe src="Inline" width="300" height="500"></iframe> 

    <a href="Download" target="download_pdf">Download File</a>
    <iframe name="download_pdf" ></iframe>
</body>
```

On server side I used servlet with Content-disposition inline and attachment.

When try to download, the pdf which is inline get vanished it shows grey colored window only and it happens only for internet explorer.

Here for downloading I am using iframe because I don't want the page to be change and any popup window to appear.

If you anyone knows other option please suggest.

Why the inline pdf contents are getting disappear?

Answer (score 0):

You can modify as

```
<a href="file.pdf" target="_blank">Download File</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but it opens a new window. I don't want that window. I only want the options for open or save to be visible.

Comment: Try <iframe src="file.pdf" width="800" height="600"></iframe>